# How would I ng-show an item if another DOM is visible?

Tags: angularjs

Would I just add ng-model to the visible/invisible DOM and then ng-show="thatElement.visiblity==='true'"?

```
<span>Show this text when the div is visible</span>
<div ng-repeat="user in users" ng-show="user.section===radio.model">{{user.name}}</div>
```

Update: If I put the Show this text when the div is visible, it's going to repeat for every user in users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restructure it:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users" ng-show="user.section===radio.model">
    <span>Show this text when the div is visible</span>
    <div>{{user.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Or, (since it wasn't clear), if you want the div to be shown all the time, and span only when the condition is met, you can do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
    <span ng-show="user.section===radio.model">Show this text when the div is visible</span>
    <div>{{user.name}}</div>
</div>
```

---

You can also use a filter that will sort out the object that enter ng-repeat so you can avoid processing unneeded subobjects like that.

---

Here's a simple example using `ng-if` on the spans:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.users = [{
      name: 'Mr. Visible',
      visibility: true
    }, {
      name: 'Mr. Invisible',
      visibility: false
    }]
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="user in users">
    <span ng-if="user.visibility">Show this text when the div is visible</span>
    <div>{{user.name}}</div>
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

---

UPDATE

Example using a boolean to denote whether to show a single span:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.users = [{
      name: 'Mr. Visible',
      visibility: true
    }, {
      name: 'Mr. Invisible',
      visibility: false
    }];

    $scope.showSpan = false;
    for (var i in $scope.users) {
      if ($scope.users[i].visibility) {
        $scope.showSpan = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <span ng-show="showSpan">Show this text when the div is visible</span>
  <div ng-repeat="user in users">
    <div>{{user.name}}</div>
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome! That's fine, then my second example will work for you. If you completely want to remove the span instead of just hiding it, you can use `ng-if`. Of course, you could achieve this for an outside element, but would involve additional models and watchers, I'd not recommend it unless **really** necessary.

Comment: Div don't have ng-models. Only the input elements (input, select, textarea...) do. See here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel  What do you want to do with it?

Comment: It won't, inspect my example. It will be there just for those with a set visibility.

Comment: Oh, that's what you want. Then simply create a new boolean variable that denotes whether the span should be shown or not, and use it with `ng-show` or `ng-if`.

Comment: Nice. So $scope.bool = search condition?

Comment: Yes, exactly! And make sure you recalculate it in case you add/remove users.

Comment: How would I do that exactly? We're working on something similar at my job. Would it be with a $watch function?

Comment: Yes, using $watch would be the best. You can also define a recalculation function and call it manually each time you need it (that's fine if you know where all the changes could come from). Btw. added an example.

Comment: Beautiful. :) You basically just did a filter in angular with one line of code!

Comment: Yup, a super-simple filter. :) You just need to modify the criteria.